# Delete large amount of Vertexs from the Cosmos Db using Gremlin queries

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have around 40000 vertexes with label Test

I am trying to delete all the vertex's but I always get query too large exception.

I tried deleting it through Azure Cosmos DB Data Explorer using the following query

> g.V().hasLabel('Test').drop()

This deletes around 200 vertex's but thats not enough for me

I also tried deleting it through the code

```
await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>("g.V().hasLabel('Test').drop()");
```

The code simply does not work and I get the same exception without deleting any vertex's

How can I delete large amount of vertexes efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that you have low Throughput (RU/s) and when the query exceeds the limit its gives too large exception.

One way you can remove the data is by applying the limit on drop

> g.V().hasLabel('Test').limit(2000).drop()

Adjust the limit according to your throughput so that it can execute the query with out throwing the exception.